# difference between Func<> and ordinary function

Tags: c#, delegates, func

```
class worker
{
    public Func<int> func1 = ()=>{ return 1; };
    public int func2()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        worker w = new worker();
        int i = w.func1.Invoke();
        int j = w.func2();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", i, j);
    }
```

What is exactly the difference between these two calls:

- `Func<>` and
- `func()`?

When should I use `Func<>`?

Comment: You don't need to do `int i = w.func1.Invoke();` - just do `int i = w.func1();`

Comment: A Func is a delegate.  Go read up on what delegates are.

Comment: OK thanks everyone. So I'm going to read about delegates. Thx again.

Comment: I do not really see this as a duplicate. He isn't asking what a delegate is, but rather what the difference is between the two tools, **Func<>** and **func()**. I would answer, but I do not know either.